# How To assign a value from postgres sql query to a field in frontend using javascript

Tags: javascript, postgresql

I Actually Have 2 fields in the front end. In which In the first field i will Auto Search the employee name for which I have Written A postgre sql query.

Now my Requirement Is As soon i select The Employee Name I need His job title To be Displayed in the next feild.

How Can I do That Using Java Script. Please Find The Query below

```
select ei.id,ei.employee_name,ro.name,um.role_id from manager_mapping mm 
left join employee_info ei on mm.typeid = ei.id  
left JOIN user_master um on um.id = ei.user_master_id   
left join role ro on ro.id = um.role_id   
where ei.employee_name ilike %:searchtxt% and ro.name='ROLE_JDM' or 
ro.name='ROLE_HEADOFF' and um.enabled = true
```

In the Above Query I want the value the value of ro.name to be displayed automatically when i select the employee name

Comment: The connection between your SQL query and JavaScript is not obvious to me, and you may want to clarify your question.

Comment: Your front-end javascript runs in the browser;  as such, it has no direct connection to the database which is in your backend.  Instead, what it does is issue (probably a GET) request to your backend (Java?) service, which runs the SQL and sends the response back to your javascript.

Comment: where is the **Java** question here?

Answer (score 0):

Create api and from front end using ajax or fetch call those api. This api will internally call the `service` which will call the `dao` which will eventually run this query.

Then send the result of the query as the `return` of the `api`. Once the ajax is successful you can assign the values to the variable in javascript

Comment: can u share me the javascript syntax for that

Comment: Check this https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch